# PHP Web Service with SOAP

Tags: php, web-services, api, soap, wsdl

I realize it's possible to create a PHP Web Service using SOAP, however, are there classes within PHP that make this easier than hand creating the SOAP messages?

I want to use php has a webservice using wsdl

with this link

https://qa-api.ukmail.com/Services/UKMAuthenticationServices/UKMAuthenticationService.svc?wsdl

to integrate uk mail api in to my php web application

but dont now how to do it ?? any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are:

- The PHP [SOAP](http://php.net/SOAP) functions
- The [PEAR::SOAP](http://pear.php.net/package/SOAP) module
- [nusoap](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nusoap/)

They *should* all interoperate fine with .NET - it's just XML after all...

Answer (score 1):

You want to try nuSOAP which you can get from here http://sourceforge.net/projects/nusoap/

Very easy as I had to create a PHP SOAP service and I didnt know PHP as I'm a C# .net person!

And just to add to that, as long as you implement the wsdl and SOAP methods correctly you should be fine. I had it working with .net with no trouble at all

Answer (score -1):

Sure...

https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.soapserver.php

There used to be an example in there somewhere... I couldn't find it though...